# How to interpret multivariable meta-regression with none predictor significant?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

How do I interpret a multivariable meta-regression model with significant test for moderators (p<0.05), but without any of the moderators included being significant on its own?

This is frequently encountered when performing multiple meta-regressions, but I was unable to found any guidance on how to interpret this results.

Suppose that I performed one multiple meta-regression with three moderators (A, B, C). They were all significant at univariate analysis; when I perform multiple meta-regression, I do get a significant "test for moderators", but none of the variables are significant on their own in the model.

Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is a situation which can occur in any form of regression not just meta-regression. Each moderator accounts for a certain amount of variance individually and together they account for more but once you have taken account of one or more moderators the others do not add very much which is what the results from the multivariable analysis are telling you. Imagine one of your moderators was dose given in the clinical trial and the other was number of tablets given per day and assume the interventional medicinal product only came in one size. Now suppose that each is a significant moderator and together they are but neither adds anything to the other since they are perfectly correlated.

Comment: I understand this, but the fact is that the multivariate model may have a much higher R-squared value compared to each of the univariate meta-regression. In this case, it is ok to report the multivariable model even if the single covariates are not significant?

Comment: The multivariable model will always have an $R^2$ at least as great as any of the individual ones. What you report depends on your scientific question.